# Trying to make button work the function but my alert is popping up the written script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function that will ask a user to pick two integers and spit out the smallest one in the form of alerts after the button is clicked. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because whatever i write in the function is coming out as an alert and not the actual event I am trying to achieve.

```
function smallestNumber() {
    var smallNumber= Math.min(prompt('pick a number').value , prompt('pick another number').value);
    console.log(smallNumber);

}

alert(smallestNumber);

document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", smallestNumber);
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>testing script</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>this button</button>
        <script src="testscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ypvL9oyd/

Answer (score 2):

It's because you named your function `smallestNumber` and your variable `smallNumber` - but you alert `smallestNumber` (the name of your function) - `alert` the correct variable!

```
alert(smallNumber)
```

And as pointed out by @AtheistP3ace - your `alert` is outside your function.

```
function smallestNumber(){
    var smallNumber = Math.min(prompt('pick a number').value , prompt('pick another number').value);
    alert(smallNumber);
}
```

Comment: They also placed their alert outside the function.

Comment: And one more thing, they aren't accessing the list getElementsByTagName returns correctly to grab a specific element so that event will never be attached to anything, if you would like to add that as well. =]

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array.

`prompt()` returns the answer directly; it's not in `prompt().value`, which is `undefined`

`prompt` returns a string, so you need to remember to parse it into an integer to use it in `Math.min()`

```
function smallestNumber(){
    var smallNumber= Math.min(parseInt(prompt('pick a number')) , parseInt(prompt('pick another number')));
    console.log(smallNumber);
    alert(smallNumber);
}
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", smallestNumber);
```